Bash using Expect script gives error for ssh call
In a bash script I have an expect segment where it sends commands to a machine via ssh. I have the bash -c there as I need to set environment variables in this command.
But I'm getting an error:
extra characters after close-quote
    while executing
"spawn -noecho ssh -t anon@machine  'bash -c "cd /tmp;"'
"

When I run that command manually ssh -t anon@machine  'bash -c "cd /tmp;"' it works fine. What is wrong here?
   ssh_param="-t ${scp_user}${_machine}  'bash -c \"cd /tmp;\"'"

    /usr/bin/expect <<-EOF1
    set timeout 360
    spawn -noecho ssh ${ssh_param}
    expect {
        "password:" { 
             send "${_pass}\r" 
         }
         eof { exit }
    }
    expect {
         eof { exit }
    }
EOF1

Also if I set ssh_param as ssh_param="-t ${scp_user}${_machine}  \"cd /tmp;\"" this works, so why does bash -c ...  cause it to fail?

Take a look at SSH key exchange.

I'm writing this script for general usage for people who may not have the ssh public private keys setup on their environments. So its better for me to use a password prompt and have them enter it manually.

Take a look at man sshpass (noninteractive ssh password provider).

expect provides an option to enable debugging output. You can include this in your script to get more information about what expect is doing. Add the following line at the beginning of your expect script:
exp_internal 1

I need this script to be able to run on windows machines as well.

You can run expect with the -d option to enable verbose debugging mode from the command line:
expect -d your_script.exp

The script is a bash script, the except portion is just for the password section in the bash script. When I added exp_internal 1 it doesn't show any other output, just the same error.

Did you try to set exp_internal 1 within expect code?  Just before set timeout 360

It's because tcl (and thus expect) doesn't have any special meaning for single quotes but does for double quotes.

I always suggest writing the entire thing in tcl/expect instead of trying to call expect from a shell script. Removes a whole layer of quote issues.

I would get rid of 'bash -c \"cd /tmp;\"' and cd to /tmp in the expect { logic

I removed the rest of the command after cd /tmp;for the post but I also need to set an environment variable and run other commands after. I can't remove cd /tmp

I'm saying to put cd /tmp in the expect code, not in your ssh connection logic. setting env vars can also be done in this way.

After bash does its parameter substitution on the heredoc, expect is run with
set timeout 360
spawn -noecho ssh -t XXXYYY 'bash -c "cd /tmp;"'
expect {
    "password:" { 
         send "ZZZ\r" 
     }
     eof { exit }
}
expect {
     eof { exit }
}

expect scripts are written in the tcl language, which basically works by splitting up a line into words and treating the first word as a command to run with the rest of the words as arguments after doing substitutions. Kind of like shell that way, but with saner rules. The 12 rules for parsing tcl are called the Dodekalogue.
Single quotes are not used to group multiple words into one - only double quotes, [] (Which indicates a command and arguments to evaluate), and {} (Which don't substitute or evaluate anything in them). So the line
spawn -noecho ssh -t XXXYYY 'bash -c "cd /tmp;"'

is split up into spawn, -noecho, ssh, -t, XXXYYY, 'bash, -c and "cd /tmp;"'. The single quote at the end after the closing double quote of the last word is an error. Normally in tcl you'd just wrap it in curly braces instead (Or double quotes but then you have to escape the nested ones):
spawn -noecho ssh -t XXXYYY {bash -c "cd /tmp;"}

which means the shell variable you set needs to look something like
ssh_param="-t ${scp_user}${_machine} {bash -c \"cd /tmp;\"}"


Writing the entire thing in tcl/expect instead of shell that builds expect scripts to execute will make life easier, as you don't have to switch between different quoting styles, worry about shell parameter expansion causing invalid tcl to be generated like this example, etc.

I will look into changing into expect, thank you so much for the {bash -c \"cd /tmp;\"} idea, that was exactly it.
